# skipLocationChange On Routes Array. Angular 11

Tags: angular

Im Curious how you skipLocationChange on the Routing Module array.

```
onst routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/login', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: 'register', component: RegisterComponent },
  { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent },
  { path: 'createentry', component: CreateentryComponent },
  { path: 'dateview', component: DateviewComponent },
  {path: 'profile', component: ProfileComponent},
  { path: 'calendar', component: CalendarComponent, resolve: { singlePost: SinglePostResolver}}
 

];
```

I automatically redirect to the login at the start, But how do I skip the Url append in here?

Comment: it is not configurable from route

Comment: Hmm, So is there anyway to get the initial pend on the first redirect gone?

Comment: I believe you still can render component or assign guard which will navigate to wherever you want without location change

Comment: Mind providing a doc or example of how I can render instead of route in the module? 
I want to adjust to guard/Auth at some point so might generically resolve this after time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is no possibility to navigate without location change in router config. you can probably make a guard which will be activated on the path navigation and will redirect everything that comes

```
const routes = [
 { path: '', canActivate: [RedirectGuard], data: {redirectTo: '/login'}, pathMatch: 'full' },
...
]
```

```
export class RedirectGuard {
  constructor(private router: Router) {}
  canActivate(routeSnapshot) {
    this.router.navigateByUrl(routeSnapshot.data.redirectTo, {skipLocationChange: true});
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi I realised now that it always redirects me to the dashboard, Because I remove Url Prefixes  when moving between components so its always " " Whats the way around that?